# Undefined al pasar variable de una función a otra

Tags: javascript, undefined

estoy intentando pasar una variable **coordestino** de una función a otra pero al querer recuperarla en esta ultima me da como resultado undefine. Alguien me podría iluminar en qué estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias

```
 var coordorigen =0.0;
 var coorddestino = 0.0;

   var boton = document.createElement('BotonBuscar');
    boton.innerHTML = 'Buscar';
    var elementoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    elementoDiv.className = 'boton-cambiar-proyeccion';
    elementoDiv.appendChild(boton);

 var map = new ol.Map({  
         view: new ol.View(),   
         layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
             source: new ol.source.OSM({
           // wrapX: true

             })
           })
           ],

            target: document.getElementById('map'),



         controls: ol.control.defaults({

             zoom: false,     
           attributionOptions: {
             collapsible: false

           }

         }),

         view: new ol.View({
             center: ol.proj.transform(
                       [longitud, latitud], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    // [0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                       zoom: 11.6,
                       minZoom: 3,
                       maxZoom: 18

             }),


       });

       var NuevoControl = new ol.control.Control({ element: elementoDiv });
        map.addControl(NuevoControl);
 //// +++++ ESTA PARTE ESTA DESTINADA AL BUSCADOR ORIGEN POR TEXTO +++++

 var geocoderdestino = new Geocoderdestino('nominatim', {
          provider: 'OSM',
         // key: 'Y1mwqAJLra9VSGEq3vx94nF8mrV6K9z2',
          lang: 'es-AR', //en-US, fr-FR
          //autoComplete: true,
          placeholder: 'Indique Destino ...',
          targetType: 'text-input',
          limit: 5,
          countrycodes:'AR',  
          keepOpen: false
        });

        map.addControl(geocoderdestino);



 var geocoder = new Geocoder('nominatim', {
      provider: 'OSM',
     // key: 'Y1mwqAJLra9VSGEq3vx94nF8mrV6K9z2',
      lang: 'es-AR', //en-US, fr-FR
      //autoComplete: true,
      placeholder: 'Indique Origen ...',
      targetType: 'text-input',
      limit: 5,
      countrycodes:'AR',
      keepOpen: false
    });

    map.addControl(geocoder);



    geocoder.on('addresschosen', function (evti){

          var featureorigen =  evti.feature,
              coordorigen = evti.coordinate,
             addressorigen = evti.address


          alert(coordorigen);
          return  coordorigen;
        });


    geocoderdestino.on('addresschosen', function (evtidestino){ 

          var feature = evtidestino.feature,
              coorddestino = evtidestino.coordinate,
              addressdestino = evtidestino.address

        alert(coorddestino);
          return coorddestino;
        }); 



//// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  //AL PRESIONAR EL BOTÓN BUSCAR LLAMA A ESTA FUNCION

  boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
     // var resultado = origenrespuesta ();

     alert (coordorigen);
     alert (coorddestino);
      var proyeccion = map.getView().getProjection().getCode();
      if (proyeccion == 'EPSG:3857') {
        proyeccion = 'EPSG:4326';
      } else {
        proyeccion = 'EPSG:3857';
      }
      var nuevaView = new ol.View({
        center: [coordorigen],
        zoom: 15,
        projection: proyeccion
      });
      map.setView(nuevaView);
    });
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco mejor el problema? ¿Qué variable es `undefined` y en qué función?

Comment: Disculpa pablo, respondo por aca y edito la publicacion es.. La variables que quiero pasar el la coordestino en la parte del boton. y me dice undefined cuando la quiero mostrar en el alert.

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la variable **coordestino**? Porque en tu código se puede ver como le asignas valores, pero no como la defines. Parece que estás definiendo la variable dentro de las funciones **origenrespuesta** y **destino**. De ser así tan solo podrías acceder a esa variable desde dentro de esas funciones. Si quieres usarla fuera de estas tendrías que definir la variable fuera, para que sea accesible.

Comment: Estimado @phpMyGuel, ahi edite el codigo para que veas donde puse las variables.. Lo que tendrian que enviar esas variables son coordenadas.

Comment: Te estás dando cuenta que la estás iniciando dos veces? arriba de todo y mas tarde dentro del handler del evento click del botón "boton" ?

Comment: @JoseFG tenes toda la razón del mundo, cuando uno anda mareado, anda mareado!! Gracias amigo

Comment: Para eso estamos, suerte